# Applications of integrals of rational functions of sine and cosine

Tags: integration, applications

I earlier asked [this question about conformal equivalence of flat tori with embedded tori](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237388/conformal-equivalence-of-tori).

In the ensuing thread the integral $\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{R+\cos x}$ occurred.  If I'm not mistaken, it was for just that integral that Euler first introduced the tangent half-angle substitution sometimes (probably incorrectly?) called the Weierstrass substitution.

So there is an application to geometry, of an integral of a rational function of sine and/or cosine.

$\Large\mathbb Q$uestion: What other applications of such integrals exist?

Answer (score 4):

Problem 1.17 of Fetter & Walecka, *Theoretical Mechanics of Particles and Continua* states the following interesting problem:

> A uniform beam of particles with energy $E$ is scattered by an attractive central potential
>
> $$V(r) = \begin{cases}0 & r \gt a\\ -V_0 & r \lt a \end{cases}$$
>
> Show that the orbit of a particle is identical with that of a light
>   ray refracted by a sphere of radius $a$ and index of refraction
>   $n=[(E+V_0)/E]^{1/2}$.  Prove that the differential cross-section for
>   $\cos{\theta/2} \gt 1/n$ is
>
> $$\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} = \frac{n^2 a^2}{4 \cos{\frac12 \theta}}
>  \frac{(n\cos{\frac12 \theta}-1)(n-\cos{\frac12 \theta})}{(1+n^2-2 n
>  \cos{\frac12 \theta})^2} $$
>
> What is the total cross-section?

In order to find the total scatter cross-section, one has to integrate over all solid angles; since the expression for the differential cross-section is independent of azimuth angle $\phi$, you end up with total cross-section

$$\sigma = \frac{n^2 a^2}{2} \int_0^{2 \arccos{(1/n)}} d\theta \, \sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} \frac{(n\cos{\frac12 \theta}-1)(n-\cos{\frac12 \theta})}{(1+n^2-2 n
 \cos{\frac12 \theta})^2}\\  = n^2 a^2 \int_0^{\arccos{(1/n)}} du \, \sin{u} \frac{(n \cos{u}-1)(n-\cos{u})}{(1+n^2-2 n \cos{u})^2}$$

So here is an example in physics of an integral over a rational function of sines and cosines.  In this case, however, the integral is pretty easy because one may substitute $v=\cos{u}$ and turn this into a simple integral over a rational function

$$\sigma = n^2 a^2 \int_{1/n}^1 dv \frac{(n v-1)(n-v)}{(1+n^2-2 n v)^2}$$

One may evaluate this integral using the substitution $w=1+n^2-2 n v$; the result is

$$\sigma = \frac12 a^2$$

Comment: @Alex M. Any idea how to simplify the numerator of the last integral by the substitution $w=1+n^2-2nv$ ? While reproducing the calculation, I have found the little error, but at the last step I have had to use the Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

To get the total cross section, you also have to integrate over the azimuthal angle. Since there is no azimuthal dependence, that will just result in a factor of $$ 2\pi $$ to the total cross section, for a final result of $$ \sigma = \frac{a^2}{2}\cdot2\pi = \pi a^2$$ This is also the cross-sectional area of the scattering potential.