# A tangent of a tangent is a product of two tangents?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

"Recall" that
$$
\frac{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta}{1+\cos\alpha\cos\beta} = \cos \gamma \quad \text{ if OR only if (I forgot which) } \quad \tan\frac\alpha2\cdot\tan\frac\beta 2 = \tan\frac\gamma 2
$$
(where the "or" is inclusive). (I never knew this identity before I derived it myself, so you can construe the word "recall" in the sense of Plato.) **PS:** There should be some absolute value signs there.

In [this answer by Lukas Geyer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237388/conformal-equivalence-of-tori/238394#238394), we see that
$$
\int_0^u \frac{dt}{R+\cos t} = \frac 2 {\sqrt{R^2-1}} \arctan\left( \tan \frac u 2 \cdot \sqrt{ \frac{R-1}{R+1}} \  \right).
$$
(He stops short of saying that explicitly except in the case where $u=2\pi$.)

Two times the arctangent of a product of tangents is what $\gamma$ is in the trigonometric identity above.  So we ask: what if the radical $\sqrt{\dfrac{R-1}{R+1}}$ were $\tan\dfrac\beta2$ for some $\beta$?  It that were true, then we would have
$$
\sqrt{\frac{R-1}{R+1}} = \tan\frac \beta 2; \quad\text{therefore} \quad \tan\beta = \sqrt{R^2-1},
$$
Letting $I$ be the integral above, we get
$$
\tan\left( \frac {I \tan\beta} 2 \right) = \tan\frac u 2\cdot \tan\frac\beta 2.
$$
This looks so weird that I am suspicious.  Does this look anything like any standard result that I've never heard of?  Is something of interest known about this?

Comment: "you can construe the word "recall" in the sense of Plato" - this is priceless, should use it on a student some day

Comment: Maybe then you should say "if XOR only if"

Comment: @Topologicalcat : That would be the opposite of what I meant.  I said "inclusive". $\qquad$